# Why would a WCF Contract include a ref/out parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I was looking at someone else's WCF service contract and noticed it was using an out parameter:

```
client.SomeMethod(parameter1, parameter2, out someOutParameter);
```

Is there a good reason for having an out parameter instead of adding it to the response?

**edit**
This is what the proxy generated:

```
public string CreateItem(string contract, string note, out string warning)
```

Now if they needed to return a string and also have a warning, I have usually seen it like this:

```
public class CreateItemResponse
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public string Warning { get; set; }
}
```

I was just curious if there was a good reason for not doing it this way, and doing it with a string being returned and a string as an out parameter.

Comment: Why not show us the actual method signature? The reason should really pop out if it is a reasonable usage of out parameters.

Comment: I added what the proxy generated for the method.

Comment: I have seen this from developers who do not know how to handle Server side exception, Fault Contracts, or from Developers who do not have much web development or Web Services experience. The warning would likely be an exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a good reason for having an out parameter instead of adding it to the response?

Not in a web service contract. Maybe laziness and unwillingness to define an additional data contract to be used as return type have been the driving forces behind this *design decision*. `out`, `ref` are .NET specific artifacts. A good and interoperable service contract shouldn't rely on language specific artifacts.

Comment: I've just noticed this same behaviour, but its not by hand. A developer generated a proxy with 'Add service reference' and the generated code actually takes the raw return type then splits the sub objects between the out parameter and the return value!!

Comment: If using 'ref' and 'out' was really a problem WCF would have given a compile error on that. But WCF is modeled on RPC style, so I think they supported out/ref to make it feel like a normal method call.

Answer (score 0):

The question has not much to do with WCF, you could question any method using a ref or an out parameter. ref and out are C# language features typically used to return more than one value type. If you don't want to use them, then don't use them. We use to say there are many ways to Rome.

The disadvantage of ref parameters is that you cannot change the contract without breaking the service interface.

EDIT: ok, there is probably no other reason than not willing to write an additional data contract.

Comment: This question has EVERYTHING to do with WCF. The contract is specifying an out parameter, and it is something I have never seen in a WCF contract before.

Comment: hmmmh. just if you have never seen it before, it does not mean it has anything to do with WCF. I agree with you it is not common and as Darin Dimitrov remarks, it might be laziness and not interoperable, but obviously it works. So what's the question?

Comment: I understand that it works. What I'm trying to find out if there is a good use case for it. I realize there are probably multiple ways to accomplish the same thing, but I have never seen it done this way. I'm just curious if there is a certain scenario where you would have to do it this way instead of the "normal" way.